# Monarch JS has not been loaded. After changing the $dep parameter, it start being loaded

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

When use this code does not work

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
   'et_monarch-custom-js', 
   ET_MONARCH_PLUGIN_URI . '/js/custom.js', 
   array( 'jquery' ), 
   $this->plugin_version, 
   true 
);
```

But this one works

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'et_monarch-custom-js', 
    ET_MONARCH_PLUGIN_URI . '/js/custom.js', 
    array(), 
    $this->plugin_version, 
    true 
);
```

Comment: What action hook are you using to execute `wp_enqueue_script`?

Comment: Hi cjbj, it has been hooked with this "wp_enqueue_scripts".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine and should work. So that leads to the conclusion that jquery is not loaded at the time you are trying to load your script. Since WP is loading jquery by default, this leaves two possibilities:

1. You are loading your script before jquery is loaded with a [high priority on you `add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)
2. You (or a plugin you are using) are deregistering jquery, possibly to register it again at a later point. Your script is trying to load right inbetween.

Comment: Thank you! You are totally right. I found "wp_deregister_script('jquery');" in my header.php. After I comment this line, the monarch jquery start being loaded.